# Why do I have different dump in PHP and JSON?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I use Laravel Eloquent for my project. I get different object results with futher coding.

Php dump (var_dump(), dd(), dump()) object without unnecessary data, file json_encode spawns calculated data including loading something what was not required.

I have two model classes:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Review extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

To get a product I use

```
$product = App\Product::find(1)
```

But since I want to send data to JSON, I need to just load it by typing:

```
$product->reviews
```

But I don't want to load it, I just want to get additional calculated data without loading all reviews inside my json

```
$product['reviews_statistics'] = count($product->reviews);
```

I expect to find out how to set data for JSON without loading all $product->reviews

Comment: show us the value of `$product` using `print_r($product);`

Comment: [This is described well in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models). 
 "_If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models._"

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend You to try eagerloading the count:

```
$product = App\Product::withCount('reviews')->find(1)
```

Comment: What about other calculations? I need some more, which I didn't write to flood this topic. I also need to get avarage of reviews['rating']

Comment: Well if You want to do it on one select, than I don't know any better way, but adding calculated columns via selectRaw. `$product = App\Product::selectRaw('*,(select avg(rating) from reviews where reviews.product_id=products.id) as rating_avg')->find(1)`